# How can Canadians recover U.S. withholding taxes on U.S. stock dividends?

Tags: investing, canada, etf, dividends, withholding-tax

I'm Canadian, but I like U.S. ETFs because there's more variety than Canadian ETFs.

1. What means ["recoverable"](https://canadiancouchpotato.com/2012/09/17/foreign-withholding-tax-explained/) below? 100% fully refundable to me?
2. How do I recover U.S. withholding taxes?
3. Why does the U.S. charge withholding taxes at all, if Canadians can 100% recover them?

> #### A. Canadian fund that holds US or international stocks directly.
>
> - In a **taxable account**, US or international withholding taxes apply, but are recoverable.
> - In an **RRSP** or **TFSA**, US or international withholding taxes apply and are not recoverable.
>
> #### B. US-listed ETF that holds US stocks.
>
> - In a **taxable account**, US withholding taxes apply, but are recoverable.
> - In an **RRSP**, US withholding taxes do not apply.
> - In a **TFSA**, US withholding taxes apply and are not recoverable.
>
> [Foreign Withholding Tax Explained | Canadian Couch Potato](https://canadiancouchpotato.com/2012/09/17/foreign-withholding-tax-explained/)
>
> #### C. US-listed ETF that holds international stocks.
>
> - In a **taxable account**, international withholding taxes apply and are not recoverable. US withholding taxes apply, but are recoverable.
> - In an **RRSP**, international withholding taxes apply and are not recoverable. US withholding taxes do not apply.
> - In a **TFSA**, international and US withholding taxes apply and are not recoverable.

Answer (score 4):

1. [Foreign tax credit](https://www.canada.ca/en/revenue-agency/services/tax/individuals/topics/about-your-tax-return/tax-return/completing-a-tax-return/deductions-credits-expenses/line-40500-federal-foreign-tax-credit.html)

> Line 40500. You may be able to claim this credit for foreign income or
>   profit taxes you paid on income you received from outside Canada and
>   reported on your Canadian tax return. Tax treaties with other
>   countries may affect whether you are eligible for this credit.

2. See 1 but also look at your T slips for "foreign tax paid"
3. The tax is paid to the US and refunded by Canada.  The same thing happens in reverse if Canada withholds tax from a US tax resident.  It's set out in a treaty.

Answer (score 0):

It may be worth noting that the FTC is a non-refundable tax credit and thus, if your income falls under an effective tax rate of less than 15%, then you won't be able to fully recover the IRS 15% Foreign Withholding tax for those US dividends.

Please [see this](https://headlinehive.com/thetravelguy/1555/can-you-get-100-of-the-us-dividend-withholding-tax-back-when-you-file-your-canadian-tax-return) for more info.